# Batch in postman

Tags: postman

I need post data from postman, but I have  results limit (200 result for one query). I have 45 000 results. In this case, I need run query a lot of times for getting all data.

```
"select" : "(**)", "start": 0, "count": 200,
"select" : "(**)", "start": 201, "count": 401,
"select" : "(**)", "start": 402, "count": 502,
"select" : "(**)", "start": 503, "count": 603
```

Do we have any ways to run query using 1000 branch for example?

Comment: Not really sure about this. Just trying to help - Have you used the collection runner?
You can run a request 'n' number of items and also you can see the data. If you want to export the data then you can use newman or there are more ways too. Let me know if collection runner helps you, I'll guide you through the process of writing all the data to a file too.

Comment: Btw, collection runner docs: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/intro_to_collection_runs